# Dojo Lazy Tree Grid - Change Data on the Grid on Demand

Tags: ajax, dojo, lazy-evaluation

I have Dojo Lazy Tree Grid. I am trying to change the data on the grid by Ajax, rather than submitting the page.

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid");
        dojo.require("dojox.grid.LazyTreeGridStoreModel");
        dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
        dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
        dojo.require("dojo.parser");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
        dojo.require("dojox.grid.cells.dijit");

    var store = "";
    var qty1 = "";

    var grid ;
    dojo.ready(function(){
        qty1 = document.getElementById("qty1").value;

    if(qty1!="")
        store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url: "serverdata.jsp?firsttimeload=false" });
    else
        store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url: "serverdata.jsp?firsttimeload=true" });


    var model = new dojox.grid.LazyTreeGridStoreModel({
          store: store,
          serverStore: true,
          childrenAttrs: ['children']
        });

    var layout = [


        {name: 'Qty1', field: 'Qty1', width: '20%'},
        {name: 'Qty2', field: 'Qty2', width: '10%',formatter: openHyperlink}
    ];
    grid = new dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        treeModel: model,
        structure: layout,
        openOnClick:true,
        rowSelector: '20px',
        canSort:false,
        rowsPerPage:'500'

  }, document.createElement('div'));


/* append the new grid to the div */
dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

/* Call startup() to render the grid */
grid.startup();

    function search()
    {
        qty1 = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
        if(qty1!="" )
        {
            grid._clearData();
            grid._size = 500;
            grid.rowsPerPage = 500; 
            grid.updateRowCount(500);
            grid._updateRenderedRows(); 
            var jsonurl = "serverdata.jsp?firsttimeload=false&qty1="+qty1;
            grid.setStore(new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url: jsonurl}));
            grid._fetch(0, true);
            grid.refresh();

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please enter atleast one search term");
        }
    }

    var openHyperlink = function(value, idx, level){

        return '<a href="#">'+value+'</a>';

        }
```

When I click Search, i call Search(), where I want to refresh the grid.
But when I keep the rowsPerPage as 500. The browser itself stops responding for a few minutes. I get a Script not responding. Is My way of refreshing the contents of the grid the right way to do it?
Please assist.

Comment: Show us the code, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Edited my post to show some code.